# I am rebuilding my retaining wall and I have a few questions pertaining backfill

Tags: landscaping

The wall had some rock backfill that was completely surrounded in fabric. While I was tearing it down, I accidentally got a good bit of dirt into the backfill.

Now as I rebuild I have been cleaning the rocks before I relay them. I am also not separating the backfill from the native soil behind the backfill like had been done previously.

Note: I know there is a bit of a lean. Without digging under the patio I couldn't undo the slight lean that it has. I am cascading the wall backwards to get it away from the porch post. Beyond that I don't really mind it.

Here is what it looks like at the moment

My questions are:

- Should I be separating the backfill from the soil? I saw that now people recommend just separating the top and bottom from the native soil.
- Should I bother washing the backfill before putting it back in? It really sucks, and takes a lot of time and I am running out of "okay" weather.
- Anything I seem to be doing inappropriately so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for using fabric between the soil and the rock backfill is to prevent soil from getting in. Soil absorbs water and the freeze thaw cycle can cause walls to fail.

Large stones or walls that are 2 or 3 feet tall or warmer climes don't have to worry so much.  If the wall is tapered back into the soil from bottom to top that helps to.

The most important thing is to use a landscape fabric

Answer (score 1):

It is best for the rocks to be dirt free.

But it depends on how much soil. If the rocks are just dirty, it won't matter so much. If there are clods of dirt, they will slowly wash down the bottom and clog up the botyom of your drainage. That will put water pressure on the wall.

Which is why slotted pipe is normally used at the bottom of the wall.